# Print text in Oracle SQL Developer SQL Worksheet window

Tags: oracle, printing, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL (in SQLDeveloper, using the SQL Worksheet).  I would like to print a statement before my select, such as

```
PRINT 'Querying Table1';
SELECT * from Table1;
```

What do I use to Print / show text output?  It's not Print, because that gives me the error: Bind Variable `Table1` is NOT DECLARED.  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE is an unknown command.  (Obviously, I'm an inexperienced SQLDeveloper and Oracle user.  There must be some synonym for Print, but I'm having trouble finding help on it without knowing what it is.)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

[image]

for simple comments:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('simple comment');
end;
/

-- do something

begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('second simple comment');
end;
/
```

you should get:

```
anonymous block completed
simple comment

anonymous block completed
second simple comment
```

if you want to print out the results of variables, here's another example:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
declare
a_comment VARCHAR2(200) :='first comment';
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(a_comment);
end;

/

-- do something


declare
a_comment VARCHAR2(200) :='comment';
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(a_comment || 2);
end;
```

your output should be:

```
anonymous block completed
first comment

anonymous block completed
comment2
```

Comment: First line set serveroutput on format wraped; should be 
set serveroutput on format WRAPPED;

Comment: I can't get this to work. 
`set serveroutput on format word_wrapped;
 begin dbms_output.put_line('hello world');
 end; 
select * from dual` 
Gives me:
 `select * from dual; Error report: ORA-06550: line 7, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" 06550. 00000 - "line %s, column %s:\n%s" *Cause: Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. *Action `

Comment: In newer versions of SQL Developer you first have to open the DBMS Output window using the topleven menu bar: View > Dbms Output.

Comment: could've but the screen shot and no text, would have been a +1 haha

Answer (score 52):

```
PROMPT text to print
```

**Note:** must use 
   Run as Script (F5)
not
   Run Statement (Ctl + Enter)

Comment: This is so useful. Thanks!

Comment: Works for me with Run Statement (Ctl + Enter) too.

Answer (score 23):

You could [set echo](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#SQPUG075) to on:

```
set echo on
REM Querying table
select * from dual;
```

In SQLDeveloper, hit F5 to run as a script.

Comment: I had accepted this as an answer, but I see another answer has a lot more points, so I changed my accept to that.  However, this did work for me, and it's a good answer.

Answer (score 23):

The main answer left out a step for new installs where one has to open up the dbms output window.

[image]

Then the script I used:

```
dbms_output.put_line('Start');
```

---

Another script:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('jabberwocky');
end;
```

Answer (score 16):

You could put your text in a select statement such as...

```
SELECT 'Querying Table1' FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, I could only get it to work with

```
set serveroutput on format word_wrapped;
```

The wraped and WRAPPED just threw errors: SQLPLUS command failed - not enough arguments

Answer (score 3):

If I ommit begin - end it is error. So for me this is working (nothing else needed):

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('testing');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want all of your SQL statements to be echoed, but you only want to see the easily identifiable results of your script, do it this way:

> set echo on
>
> REM MyFirstTable
>
> set echo off
>
> delete from MyFirstTable;
>
> set echo on
>
> REM MySecondTable
>
> set echo off
>
> delete from MySecondTable;

The output from the above example will look something like this:

> -REM MyFirstTable
>
> 13 rows deleted.
>
> -REM MySecondTable
>
> 27 rows deleted.