# How do I select a variables value in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Problem**

I just want to see the value of a variable. I don't understand why this has to be so difficult.

**My SQL Statement**

```
--set serveroutput on format wrapped; Tried this too
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
--DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(32000); Tried with, and without this

vend_num xx.VENDOR_CWT.VEND_NO%TYPE;
SELECT vend_no 
INTO vend_num 
FROM xx.VENDOR_NAME 
WHERE VENDOR_NAME1 = 'xxxx';

dbms_output.put_line(vend_num);
```

**The Error I'm Geting**

```
Error starting at line 13 in command:
dbms_output.put_line(vend_num)
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried the following answers:

[Print text in Oracle SQL Developer SQL Worksheet window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193107/print-text-in-oracle-sql-developer-sql-worksheet-window)

[Printing the value of a variable in SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887413/printing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-developer)

I've done what this answer suggested with the gui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889380/496680

I've tried `exec dbms_output[...]` as some posts have suggested.

**Question**

How do I just print the value of vend_num;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBMS_Output is a PL/SQL package, so you'd call it from within PL/SQL code.

```
declare
  end_num xx.VENDOR_CWT.VEND_NO%TYPE;
begin
  SELECT vend_no
  INTO   vend_num
  FROM   xx.VENDOR_NAME
  WHERE  VENDOR_NAME1 = 'xxxx';
  dbms_output.put_line(vend_num);
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent way too long on this :/

Comment: I could sense the frustration seeping though.